# Using external images on geoserver with dynamic url

Tags: geoserver, symbology, sld

I'm trying to get dynamic icon loading based on an attribute in GeoServer 2.9

My SLD:

```
<sld:ExternalGraphic>
    <sld:OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="icons/$(strReplace(strReplace(iconPath,'.','/',true),'/vsd','.bmp', false)"/>
    <sld:Format>image/bmp</sld:Format>
</ExternalGraphic>
```

iconpath attribute example:

```
Spot.Undefiend Spot.vsd
```

wanted url path:

```
icons/Spot/Undefiend Spot.bmp
```

I can't seem to get this working, the log isn't helpful either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the `strReplace` [documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/filter/function_reference.html#string-functions) you will see that it is a thin wrapper around the Java replace method and provides a link to the [Pattern Rules](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). This means that your function:

```
strReplace(iconPath,'.','/',true)
```

will replace every character (a `.` matches any character) in `iconPath` with a `/` - clearly not what you want. I would try something like:

```
$(strReplace(strReplace(iconPath,'\.','/',false),'\.vsd$','.bmp$', false)
```

I'm fairly sure turning the logging level up to Developer will show you what is being searched for. One other trick for debugging this sort of issue is to use a `TextSymboliser` to print the result in a label.